# Get a word using php regular expression from string

Tags: php, regex

This is my strings

```
905 Lumens/7.2W/3000K/82CRI/L85 50Khrs
1224 Lumens - 9.6W - 3000K
1632 3000K 12.8W 50Khrs
2448 Lumens/3000K/19.2W 150Khrs
```

Now I want to get only the word that have number with **W** Like: **7.2W**, **9.6W**

I want to get this in a variable using regular expression.

My code is:  `$watt = preg_match("/[\d]+W/", $string);`

currently my code return with array, but I want only string with 7.2W or 9.6W or similar ..

Please help.

Comment: What array does this code return?

Comment: its return blank array

Comment: Can you show us the expected output please? Do you need the entire line or just the word? What are the delimiters?

Comment: I need the only output... like if `$string = "905 Lumens/7.2W/3000K/82CRI/L85 50Khrs";` then I need only **7.2W** from here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all - founded matches are gathered in a third argument `$matches`.

Second - you need to consider a dot(`.`) in your regexp:

```
preg_match("/(\d+\.\d+W)/", $string, $matches);
print_r($matches);
echo $matches[0];   // full match found
```

If `.` is optional - then:

```
preg_match("/(\d+(\.{0,1})\d+W)/", $string, $matches);
print_r($matches);
echo $matches[0];   // full match found
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a lot :)